# GCP health check for internal load balancer

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform, google-health, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

I  set up own Elasticsearch cluster in the GCP. The cluster is up and running fine.

The cluster contains two `client` nodes which I am able to access internally and pass a health check for both of them using `http://IP:9200/` and `/http://IP:9200/_cluster/health`. All nodes have only private IPs.

I added:

- internal load balancer which spans `client` nodes only,
- firewall rule whitelisting both: `130.211.0.0/22, 35.191.0.0/16` google health check IP ranges with the proper tag,
- proper tag for the above rule to the `client` hosts,
- google health check if service is available,
- backend and instance groups.

The problem is all `client` hosts are added to the load balancer but any is marked as healthy.

Can you please advise if I am missing something?

Is it possible to pass a health check on the instance which doesn't have a public IP?

Thanks,
Karol

Comment: You have the backend and instance group too? (just checking to be sure)

Comment: Yeap, I have it all.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, even Google is wrong with his documentation and external IP is needed.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/cross-region-example#optional_removing_external_ips_except_for_a_bastion_host

Answer (score 0):

External or public IP is not a requirement to pass a health check.Since health checks are failing for Internal load balancer, I would recommend to check the following:

- Clients should be in the same region but can be located in different subnet.
- Make sure that service is not bind to any specific IP rather bind to all IP addresses i.e 0.0.0.0/0.